# background color for a path element on different screen sizes

Tags: svg

I have a path element which is basically a circle with something inside.

I want the path element to have background with a specific color.

I see that I need to add a rect before the path.

I'm working on a laptop so I did the following:

```
<g>
<rect width="1.1%" height="1.4%" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>
<path/>
</g>
```

It looked fine but when I *switched to a big screen*, the rect's with became a *little wider than it should*.

The SVG is:

```
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;</svg>
```

I tried to a a viewbox:

```
viewBox="0 0 100 100"
```

But it caused the react to totally not be under the path. (I might be doing it wrong)

Any idea how to handle it?

Comment: If you use a viewBox you'd normally use absolute i.e. px units rather than percentage units. If you use percentage units you'd typically not use a viewBox so which is it?

Comment: @RobertLongson - The current state is percentage on the svg element

Comment: Well path elements can't use percentage units so you probably need to switch.

Comment: Not sure I got it.
I'm not using percentage on the path but on the SVG.
I'm probably missing a thing or two. Can you clarify please :)

Comment: <rect width="1.1%" height="1.4%" <-- those are percentages

Comment: @RobertLongson - my bad. you are right. changing the rect to pixel numbers worked